# how to turn off parent recycler view onclick response after child view already responded?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I am using a recyclerview that the viewholder entry has an imageview.  Both have an onclick listener.  If the child image view responded to the onclick, I don't want the recylerview onClick to respond to it.  If the clicked location is not on the imageviewer, I want the recyclerview to respond.  My research so far shows that usually this situation can be handled by using the same function to respond to both onClick events, but the problem is that recyclerview onclick and its child imageview onClick are different.  I don't see how they can be handled in the same function.  Right now I have a hacking workaround to use a global variable to indicate that the imageview has already responded to this click, and put up a 200ms delay on recyclerview listener to check the global variable before responding.  Is there a more proper way of doing this?

I just noticed that if I add an "onClick" for every type of child views of the recycler view and remove the listener on the recyclerview, that can work.  Right now I only have two child views anyway.  Although I will be adding a lot more, it's still manageable.  If there's no better way, I'll probably just do that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:focusable="true"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="4dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lstItemName"
    android:textColor="@color/title"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/lstItemReportby"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/lstItemMap"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


public class TrackedItemListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TrackedItemListAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView m_itemName, m_itemDes, m_itemReportedBy, m_itemHiddenText;
    public ImageView m_itemMapDrop;


    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        m_itemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lstItemName);
        m_itemMapDrop = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.lstItemMap);
    }
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TrackedItemListAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.m_itemName.setText(obj.getName());
        holder.m_itemMapDrop.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_img_nomap);

        holder.m_itemMapDrop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startMap();
            }
        });
    }
}


m_trackedItemListAdapter = new TrackedItemListAdapter();
    m_recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    m_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    m_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    m_recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    m_recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        m_recyclerView.setAdapter(m_trackedItemListAdapter);
            m_recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), m_recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {


                //a hack to turn off response if the imageview for location already responded
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        popupItemContent();
                    }
                }, 200);

            }

        }
```

Comment: I don't really see how 2 completely different views can eventually end up sharing the same onClickListener unless you manually assign it that way. Would you mind sharing some of your code? The ViewHolder, Adapter and Layout specifically.

Answer (score 0):

use this in your ConstraintLayout:

```
descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Comment: I tried all values for this keyword, doesn't seem to do anything.  When I click on my image, I still get two actions.    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
...
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">